# Powershell .Contains returning False no matter what

Tags: powershell

im trying to return if a user is part of a specified group via a cmd command.
But no matter what I try, it always returns False.

```
$Test = cmd.exe /c 'net user B02201R /domain'
$Test.Contains('INet-User')
```

I know the user is part of this group and if I echo $test I can see it in the results.
What am I doing wrong here?

Type of $Test:

```
$Test.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                      
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                      
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

Comment: What is inside `$Test`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.Contains()` looks for the WHOLE object inside the collection(`$Test` in this case).
`'INet-User'` is a substring inside one of the elements of `$Test`, so it doesn't find it.

use `[bool]($Test -match 'INet-User')` instead: `-match` will parse the whole collection for it, returning every matching element or returning `$null` if it finds nothing.

Enclosing it in `[bool]()` will cast it to a simple true\false boolean.

Comment: That isn't actually correct about .contains().  The explanation is weirder.

Comment: Yeah, but I thought to keep it as simple as possible. If you find a good link I'll add it to the answer

Comment: No, you're right.  It's running `bool IList.Contains(System.Object value)` with arrays vs `bool Contains(string value)` with one string element.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, you're using `Compare` against an array/collection, not against a string.

```
@('x','xinet-Userx','INet-User','y').Contains('INet-User')
```

That's a different function: [MS Docs on Contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icollection-1.contains?view=net-8.0).  It's doing a similar operation to powershell's `-contains` or `-in` operators:

```
@('x','xinet-Userx','INet-User','y') -contains 'INet-User'
# or
'INet-User' -in @('x','xinet-Userx','INet-User','y')
```

To use the string method, convert your input to a single string via one of these methods:

```
(@('x','xinet-Userx','INet-User','y') -join '').Contains('INet-User')
# or
([string]@('x','xinet-Userx','INet-User','y')).Contains('INet-User')
# or
(@('x','xinet-Userx','INet-User','y') | Out-String).Contains('INet-User')
```

Note: String's `Contains` method is case sensitive; if you want to avoid that, pass a second argument to change how string equality is evaluated:

```
'xinet-UsErx'.Contains('INet-User', [System.StringComparison]::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like .contains() works differently with arrays than single strings.  [IList.Contains()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ilist.contains?view=net-8.0) only matches whole array elements.  After -join, it does what you expect.  Don't forget that it's case sensitive.

```
(echo one two three).contains

OverloadDefinitions
-------------------
bool IList.Contains(System.Object value)



('two').contains

OverloadDefinitions
-------------------
bool Contains(string value)


(-join (echo one two three)).contains('tw')
True
```

Comment: while it might be a bit counter-intuitive, it's perfectly simple: `(net user)` generates a collection of `[Object]`. No element in the collection is a simple string so the matchmaking fails. `Foreach-Object` otherwise cause the comparison being applied to the CONTENTS of each Object, and some of them match. `.toString()` in this instance returns only a string with the type, `System.Object[]`, which obviously does not contain `Administrator`. Last, encapsulating it between souble quotes force its contents into  single string... that contains 'Administrator'